# Uncaught JS error at Extbase extension sort records in list view

Tags: javascript, typo3, extbase

I'm trying to sort the records created through my TYPO3 extension in the list view. This is my TCA for that table:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_trends_domain_model_gallery'] = array(
    'ctrl' => array(
        'title' => 'LLL:EXT:trends/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_trends_domain_model_gallery',
        'label' => 'description',
        'tstamp' => 'tstamp',
        'crdate' => 'crdate',
        'cruser_id' => 'cruser_id',
        'dividers2tabs' => TRUE,
        'sortby' => 'sorting',
        'versioningWS' => 2,
        'versioning_followPages' => TRUE,

        'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
        'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
        'transOrigDiffSourceField' => 'l10n_diffsource',
        'delete' => 'deleted',
        'enablecolumns' => array(
            'disabled' => 'hidden',
            'starttime' => 'starttime',
            'endtime' => 'endtime',
        ),
        'searchFields' => 'images,description,trends,',
        'dynamicConfigFile' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath($_EXTKEY) . 'Configuration/TCA/Gallery.php',
        'iconfile' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extRelPath($_EXTKEY) . 'Resources/Public/Icons/tx_trends_domain_model_gallery.gif'
    ),
);
```

I added the sorting field in the table and I can see the two arrow buttons in the BE (move up/down). When I click that button however, I get the following JS error in my chrome devtools: 
`Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer..
A colleague told me that we modified an extension called grid_elements, so that it works with TYPO3 7.4.0. This extension hooked in the backend with some inline javascripts. These scripts had some errors in it (double quotes, wrong escaping). This was causing the bug where I was unable to move records in the list view up and down. It's fixed now.